# Задача Питон Генераторы

Tags: python

Написал такой код. Нужно найти числа, которые после попарного умножения дают 56. Сказали, что код верный, но некрасивый выход из цикла. Как его можно реализовать с помощью генератора?

```
list_1 = [2, 5, 7, 10]
list_2 = [3, 8, 4, 9]

to_find = 56

can_continue = True

for x in list_1:
    for y in list_2:
        result = x * y
        print(x, y, result)
        if result == to_find:
            print('Found!!!')
            can_continue = False
            break
    if not can_continue:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
to_find = 56

def gen():
    list_1 = [2, 5, 7, 10]
    list_2 = [3, 8, 4, 9]
    for x in list_1:
        for y in list_2:
            yield x, y, x * y

for x, y, result in gen():
    print(x,y,result)
    if result == to_find:
        print('Found!!!')
        break
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Наверное, правильнее всё-таки было бы передавать списки в функцию-генератор снаружи, чтобы функция была более универсальная. Да и проверку с прерыванием цикла через `return` тоже можно было бы в функции сделать, проверочное число тоже передавать параметром. Ну, как вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Можно это реализовать таким способом:

```
list_1 = [2, 5, 7, 10];
list_2 = [3, 8, 4, 9];

to_find = 56;

lst = [(x, y, x*y) for x in list_1 for y in list_2];
for itm in lst:
    print(itm);
    if (itm[2] == to_find):
        print('Found!!!');
        break;
```

А если не нужна вся история, то можно сделать таким способом:

```
list_1 = [2, 5, 7, 10];
list_2 = [3, 8, 4, 9];

to_find = 56;

lst = [(x, y, x*y) for x in list_1 for y in list_2 if (x*y == to_find)];
if (lst):
    print(lst[0]);
    print('Found!!!');
```

Answer (score 1):

вот тоже вариант с генератором:

```
list_1 = [2, 5, 7, 10]
list_2 = [3, 8, 4, 9]
to_find = 56

res = next(([x,y] for x in list_1 for y in list_2 if x*y==to_find), None)
if res: print('Found!!!', *res)  # Found!!! 7 8
```